# After modifying an STL list, does the beginning iterator need updating?

Tags: list, stl, iterator

I have an STL list L with iterator it = L.begin(). If I modify the list by say popping out elements from the front and pushing in elements from the back in a while loop, do I need to update the iterator "it" at every phase of the loop? Whether I do this or not, the program compiles in Visual Studio but when running I get a windows error saying :

list iterator not dereferencable

I did look up this error but could not fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: The documentation is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), the 2nd sentence.

Comment: Try to post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).